# must declare the scalar variable "@OTitle@FirstName"

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, sql-server-2008

I know why I am getting the error and I don't know what the code is

The error I am getting is

```
must declare the scalar variable "@OTitle@FirstName"
```

My method looks something like this..

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into MainTable(ID, Title, OTitle, FirstName, LastName,... 
VALUES(@ID, @Title, @OTitle" + 
"@FirstName, @LastName, @MiddleName..)";
```

I know the + sign does not work so my question is how do I continue on the next line.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This part of your query:

```
VALUES(@ID, @Title, @OTitle" + 
"@FirstName, @LastName, @MiddleName..
```

Turns into:

```
VALUES(@ID, @Title, @OTitle@FirstName, @LastName, @MiddleName..
```

Change the `values` line to:

```
VALUES(@ID, @Title, @OTitle, " +
```